# Comparison if else in inStream Bluetooth

Tags: android

I created an application that receives data through bluetooth for android, created a Toast What do'm getting to test, and everything is working corretamentamente, my only doubt is how can I use if else and compare What do'm getting the bluetooth?

```
        byte[] msgReceiveBuffer = new byte[5];

        int bytes = inStream.read(msgReceiveBuffer);

        if(bytes == "c")
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "OK", 0).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", 0).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not terribly clear what you're asking, but the variable `bytes` is an int which shows the number of items in the buffer. You'll want to use this for the upper limit of a `for` loop, eg:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
 byte b = msgReceiveBuffer[i];
 if(b == 'c') {
  // do what you want
 }
 else {
  // do something else
 }
}
```

I would highly recommend to check out the source code of [BlueTerm](http://pymasde.es/blueterm/) application. I found it very helpful to understand Bluetooth and Android.